# What is the probability of picking a random number from 1 to 100, 100 times, and getting each number from 1 to 100?

Tags: probability

Say I pick a number from 1 to 100, and repeat this process 99 more times. What is the probability that no numbers will repeat?

Is it correct to say the answer is 1/100! or is there more to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any number $1$ to $100$ can be the first, which occurs with probability $p_1 = 1$.

The second number must be any but the first, $p_2 = 99/100$

The third any but the first two, $p_3 = 98/100$

and so on.

Hence the desired probability is

$$\prod_{n=1}^{100} p_n = \frac{99!}{100^{99}} \approx 10^{-42}$$

which we can also write more pleasingly as $\displaystyle\frac{100!}{100^{100}}$.

By the way, this is about $116$ orders of magnitude larger than $1/100!$.

Answer (score 2):

No, you are picking with replacement.  There are $100^{100}$ ways to pick the numbers.  Of those $100!$ have no repeats, as you have $100$ choices for the first one, then $99$ choices that do not duplicate for the second, and so on.  The probability is then $\frac {100!}{100^{100}}$

Comment: Without replacement, the probability would of course be $1$.

Answer (score 1):

There are $100^{100}$ different ways to a between $1$ and $100$ a hundred times, but only $100!$ ways if you do not allow repeats, so the probability is $100! \over 100^{100}$